# Getting list of products by category in Magento using SOAP-based API

Tags: php, web-services, magento

I need to get all products belonging to a specific category in Magento using the web services API.  I tried this method:

```
$product_filter = array(
        'category_ids' => array('eq' => '41')
    );

$product_templates = $magento_client -> call($magento_session, 'product.list');
```

But it returns an error. I can only assume it's because `category_ids` is an array, so it won't really ever equal one specific value.

I did some research and found another method called `category.assignedProducts` and tried:

```
$product_templates = 
$magento_client -> 
    call($magento_session, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', array('41'));
```

But this returned an 'Access Denied' error.  I went and looked at my sandbox of Magneto and saw that 'Assigned Products' has 3 options: 'Remove', 'Update', 'Assign', and I know that the admin for the system I'm linking to has set my access to 'Read-Only'. So I'm guessing that we'd have to check off 'assign' in that list, which would give me more access than they want to give.

I could retrieve all of the data and do the filtering on my end, but I wanted to check if anyone knew of a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`assignedProducts` sounds like what you need but you shouldn't need to be passing along an array but an integer value and the store ID or code.

See the arguments required: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_category#catalog_category.assignedproducts

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer on http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/207099/ which basically says it can't be done from the product any more. We must now look at the problem from the category point of view.

> category_ids no longer works in 1.4, they changed the table
>   structures around so that the categories are not available on the
>   product.  Use the code below to get the products from the category and
>   then do a catalog_product.list call.  To make it faster you can also
>   create a custom api solution to combine these in Magento and perform
>   just one call instead of two.
>
> $proxy = new SoapClient($soapUrl.’api/soap/?wsdl’); $sessionId =
>   $proxy->login($apiUser, $apiPass);
>
> $productList = $proxy->call($sessionId,
>   ‘catalog_category.assignedProducts’, array(’4’));
>   $proxy->endSession($sessionId); print_r($productList);